# "...one of the best movies of my childhood" or "...one of the best movies from my childhood"?

Tags: grammar, usage

Are these sentences interchangeable?

> **It is one of the best movies of my childhood.**
>
> **It is one of the best movies from my childhood.**

*Context:* Let's say someone mentioned the name of a movie and I am commenting on that movie.

*My opinion:* I usually prefer to say "from", but "of" is also usable I guess.

Comment: In this context there is virtually no difference between *of* and *from*.

Answer (score 1):

As Robusto commented, there is 'virtually' no difference between the sentences, and so they are interchangeable in the context you have given.

A more nuanced answer would be that the two sentences have slightly different connotations.

*It is one of the best movies of my childhood* is the cleaner, clearer, purer sentence of the two - it refers solely to your childhood in the sense that no other part of your life is being considered.

When you say *It is one of the best movies from my childhood ...* it is almost as if you are putting emphasis on the word childhood. This would indicate that you are comparing this period of your life with other periods. You could follow this with (something like) '... but when you talk about my *university years*, then that's a whole different thing!'

Comment: I don’t disagree with your point but another person might say “of my childhood’ to indicate it is a movie the author saw at that time and might say “from’ to mean it dates from the period of that person’s childhood without necessarily being something they personally experienced at that time.